# unit ball in L^inf, and its 'closedness' in two different topologies (proof check)

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

Suppose $\mu$ is a finite measure space.
Let $1 \le p < \infty$ so that $L^\infty(\mu) \subset L^p(\mu)$.

Let $B^\infty$ be the unit ball in $L^\infty(\mu)$, so we have
$B^\infty \subset L^\infty(\mu) \subset L^p(\mu)$.

It is clear that $B^\infty$ is closed in $L^\infty(\mu)$,
but what about in $L^p(\mu)$ ?  (same set, different topology).

Claim:  $B^\infty$ is closed in $L^p(\mu)$

Proof: Let {$f_n$} be a sequence in $B^\infty$.
Then $|f_n(x)| \le 1$ almost everywhere.
Since elements of $L^\infty(\mu)$ are really
just equivalence classes, we can redefine $f_n$ on the exceptional set
of measure $0$ so $|f_n(x)| \le 1$.
Now suppose that $f_n \to f$ in the $L^p(\mu)$ topology.
Then {$f_n$} has a subsequence that converges to $f$ pointwise a.e.
(Theorem 3.12 in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis).
It follows that $|f(x)| \le 1$ a.e. and so $f \in B^\infty$. QED

Thank you for checking this proposed proof,
Glenn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean if $f_n \in B^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence for $\|.\|_{L^p}$ then $\exists f \in B^\infty$ such that $f_n \to f$. Yes but Rudin's theorem is not needed.

Since it is complete, let $f$ such that $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$.

$\forall x,|f_n(x)| \le 1$ and $\|f_n-f\|<\epsilon$ means that $$\forall \delta > 0, \qquad \|f_n-f\|_{L^p}^p \ge \delta\ \mu(1_{|f| > 1+\delta})  \implies \mu(1_{|f| > 1+\delta})  < \epsilon^p/\delta$$

Thus
$$\forall \delta > 0,\quad \mu(1_{|f| > 1+\delta}) = 0\quad \implies \quad\|f-f 1_{|f| \le 1}\|_{L^p} = 0 \implies f_n \to f 1_{|f| \le 1}\in B^\infty$$

Comment: I follow it; it's good to see a very direct argument, thanks for that.  I think there is tiny typo at the end of the last line - should be $\delta^p$ (but it makes no difference).